# Spring reactive security with OAUTH2 not able to exclude end points(401 returned all times)

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, spring-security-oauth2

Am building the reactive rest APIs with reactive security implementation. But am unable to exclude some of the end points from OAUTH2 server(Health check end point). Even though am adding those in my security configuration its not working. It always return 401 request for that end point.

My Security configuration class would be

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeExchange(exchange -> exchange.pathMatchers("/myapp/healthcheck")
                        .permitAll()
                        .anyExchange()
                        .authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 ->
                        oauth2
                                .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults())
                )
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: your configuration looks correct and I was able to validate it in my test project. try to enable debug and see where it's failing.

Comment: can you please enable spring security debug logs and post the full logs here. Also i dont see a CORS configuration.